# Use JavaScript to Log input

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have an input field, I want to write the inputs to a logger on each keystroke after they exceed three characters. The application is Rails and JavaScript. What would be the best method to go about this?

I thought about putting an event listener on the input field that happens on keyup, takes the value of the field and does something with it. I'd like to use the Ruby Logger though if possible, i.e. `Logger.new`

Example

Type 'cat'

and javascript captures the input and Logs it to log/keys.log

Type an extra 's'

and javascript captures that input and logs it to log/keys.log as well

Comment: Since you're using ROR then jQuery + AJAX might be a solution

Comment: I got the listener working

    $("#input").keyup(function() {
      $.get($(this).val());

Now I need to send the input text to Ruby to write to a file. How do I do this?

Comment: You look for Ajax tutorial. Create an action on one of your controller that receive the Ajax call and write the logs.